# how to store a link in a database and retrieve it with Jinja

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I am trying to store link in database and retrieve it with Jinja.

but when I do the browser destination is: http://127.0.0.1:5000/**url_for('portugal')**

instead of http://127.0.0.1:5000/portugal

This is what my href looks like:

```
<a href="{{ mycountry.html_page }}"
```

I think the problem is that I stored "url_for('portugal') in my database.
What should I store in my database and how should I query it?

Comment: So I found a way to make it work using http://127.0.0.1:5000/portugal in my database. But is it a good way to do it? Shouldn't  I be using url_for() instead?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely use `url_for()`, just name your route with `endpoint` parameter. e.g. `@app.route('/', endpoint='portugal')` then `url_for('portugal')`.